# Keeping jQuery Updated via NuGet

Tags: jquery, nuget

When I add the latest jQuery package via NuGet, it downloads the jQuery script files to `~/packages/jQuery.1.7.1/Content/Scripts`.

What's the best way to keep these updated in my MVC app's `~/Scripts/` folder, where I can reference them from my master page?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

> When I add the latset jQuery package via NuGet, it downloads the
>   jQuery script files to ~/packages/jQuery.1.7.1/Content/Scripts.

In addition to that the NuGet package copies the `jquery-1.7.1.js` file to the `~/Scripts` folder from where you can directly reference it.

But if you are developing a website visible from the internet it would be better to use a CDN to serve those scripts from to improve performance of your site. Google [provides one](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html).

Comment: Microsoft has a CDN as well:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_Releases_on_the_CDN_0
including the vsdoc files.